# Splitting the Java builder to avoid writing same code multiple times

Tags: java

I have a piece of code which looks like below:

```
Problem hashProblem;
String indexName;
if(condition.getOwner() != null) {
    indexName = sourceLocation ;
    hashProblem = new Problem().builder()
        .locationID(condition.getLocationID())
        .sourceLocation(condition.getSourceLocation())
        .build();
}
else {
    indexName = currentLocation;
    hashProblem = new Problem().builder()
        .locationID(condition.getLocationID())
        .currentLocation(criteria.getcurrentLocation())
        .build();
}
```

Is there a way to write this code in a more elegant way? While building the hashProblem object setting the locationID is always required. I am unable to think of a way to split the builder so that I could write .locationID only once.

Comment: What's wrong about simply using the ternary operator twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The builder instance can be extracted into a dedicated reference and you'll be able to apply the common instructions on it only once, for example:

```
final Problem.Builder builder = new Problem().builder().locationID(condition.getLocationID());
final String indexName;
if (condition.getOwner() != null) {
  indexName = sourceLocation;
  builder.sourceLocation(condition.getSourceLocation());
} else {
  indexName = currentLocation;
  builder.currentLocation(criteria.getcurrentLocation());
}
final Problem hashProblem = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is called *feature envy*. You make a decision on a property of `condition` just to get some other property out of the same object. The violated OO principle is *tell, don't ask!*

The better solution is to create 2 new methods in the type of `condition`:

```
public String selectIndexName(String sourceLocation,String currentLocation){
 return null== getOwner()?sourceLocation:currentLocation;
}
public Problem.Builder setLocationIn( Problem.Builder builder){
 if( null== getOwner()){
   builder.sourceLocation(getSourceLocation());
 else
   builder.currentLocation(getCurrentLocation());
 return builder;
}
```

Your code change to:

```
String indexName = condition.getIndexName();
Problem  hashProblem = condition.setLocationIn(
            new Problem().builder()
                         .locationID(condition.getLocationID())
         ).build();
```

Or you go one step further an move the complete functionality to `condition`:

```
// selectIndexName() as before 

public Problem.Builder configureProblem(Problem.Builder builder){
  builder.locationID(getLocationID());
  if( null== getOwner()){
       builder.sourceLocation(getSourceLocation());
  else
       builder.currentLocation(getCurrentLocation());
  return builder;
}
```

This turns your code into:

```
String indexName = condition.getIndexName();
Problem hashProblem = condition.configureProblem(new Problem().builder()).build();
```